# Unload externally loaded SWF when clicked outside SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a button on stage which loads an external SWF using the Loader class. I want to be able to unload the SWF when a user clicks outside of it, i.e. anywhere else on the stage.

So far I only have the code to load the SWF...

```
mybutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_LoadExternalSwf);

function fl_LoadExternalSwf(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var my_Loader:Loader = new Loader();
var my_url:URLRequest=new URLRequest("pageFlip.swf");

//These listeners detect when the file has finished loading, and if the
//correct file is loaded.
my_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, finishLoading);
my_Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);

//The load method then loads the SWF file into the loader object.
my_Loader.load(my_url);

//This function adds the external SWF to the stage.
function finishLoading(loadEvent:Event) {
addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
}

//This function displays a message if the file is not found.
function errorHandler(errorEvent:Event):void {
trace("file missing");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `unload()` of the `Loader()` class

```
function unloadMC(myLoader:Loader, myURL:URLRequest):void {
 myLoader.unLoad(myURL);
}

unloadMC(my_Loader, my_url);
```

**Edit**

You need an external interface to call the click event "except" the swf. First of all you would need to use jQuery to achieve

```
$(document).bind('click', function (e) {
 $('#yourSWFObject').clickOutside();
});

$('#special').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

the click method. Afterwards you need to apply the externalInterface from AS3 by using

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
public function clickOutside() {
 unloadMC(my_Loader, my_url);
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! But how do I call this function when the user clicks outside of the SWF?

Comment: Just to clarify in case the OP didn't understand: to detect clicks outside of Flash you need to use Javascript. Toxicate20 is proposing to use jQuery to detect those clicks in the HTML, and communicate to Flash via external interface when that happens.